# Perl date format transformations

Tags: perl, date

I'm taking `02/29/2012` from an html form, but will need to work with the ISO `2012-02-29` from then on. 
I am certain that it'd be easier for me to do it with Perl without touching on the JS datepicker of which I have zero understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$date = '02/29/2012';
$date =~ s#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#$3-$1-$2#;
```

Comment: As the input is not trusted (web form...) the input format should be checked more strictly. Note in particular that `\d` matches any Unicode digit, not just ASCII digits. So choroba's answer is safer.

Answer (score 5):

To do your transformation, just use

```
s{([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})}{$3-$2-$1}
```

But AFAIK, ISO is not YYYY-DD-MM, but YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: ISO 8601 (the relevant standard) does indeed use YYYY-MM-DD for dates (unless you're working with weeks, in which case you use YYYY-Www-d, or you're working with ordinal dates YYYY-DDD for year and number of day within year, etc.).

Comment: Your input format is very rigid; it rejects single digits for day or month and anything other than 4 digits for the year.  That's not necessarily a major problem, but being flexible in what you accept and rigid in what you generate is often a good system, especially if people are generating the input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) or [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aManip). There are a plenty of subroutines that perform various manipulations with date. For example, using Date::Manip:

```
$string = '02/29/2012';
$date = ParseDate($string);
$out = UnixDate($date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Edit: as I see, a similar answer was provided while I was typing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date::Manip::Date](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.30/lib/Date/Manip/Date.pod) module.

This is a little costlier but does validation of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $date = '02/09/2012';

say join '-', (split m|/|, $date)[2,1,0];
```

Using DateTime:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = '02/09/2012';

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
               pattern => '%d/%m/%Y',
             );

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime($date);
say $dt->ymd;
```

If you want to deal with dates and times in Perl, then DateTime and its friends are the tools that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much work you're going to be doing on the dates, and whether you're going to be culturally aware of how different people enter dates, and whether you're going to accept month names or abbreviations as well as pure numerics, and ...

On [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/), there's a major section on [Data and Data Types](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Data_and_Data_Types) which has sub-sections for [Date](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Data_and_Data_Types/Date) and [Time](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Data_and_Data_Types/Time) with many modules in each.  Some are extremely elaborate: for example, the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module is extremely thorough, but rather heavy-weight (and is listed in neither the Date nor the Time section).  Others are just clever: [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aCalc) and [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aManip).  The main problem at CPAN is the embarrassment of riches - what you need is probably there.

If the simple regexes in other answers will work, use them.  Otherwise, consider one of Date::Calc or Date::Manip, unless you find something else that will work better for you.

Comment: Yes noted, the regex works (and its for a very confined set of users), bearing in mind upcoming HTML5 input features I'd rader keep the script easily adaptable and on standby to get rid of the JS chooser.

Answer (score 0):

The `strptime` function can also be leveraged from the core module, [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece-1.20/Piece.pm) :

```
use Time::Piece;
my $date = q(02/29/2012);
my $t    = Time::Piece->strptime( $date, "%m/%d/%Y" );
print $t->ymd, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the input is not trusted (web form...) I suggest to basically use choroba's answer (with bounds checking added), but in a test that checks if the input matches:

```
# input and result are in $_
unless (s{^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$}{$3-$2-$1}) {
    die "invalid input";
}
# From here input is both validated and transformed
```